# How get get the entered values from input box and not the content of Value attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, input

I have some input fields with pre-populated values. After editing the values of this field if the save button is pressed in my script tag I want to take the edited value in the field and send it to my controller using ajax. The problem I faced is when I am picking the value of my input field using

```js
var name = document.getElementById('iusername').value;
```

I am getting the value in value attribute and not the one resulted after edit.

Comment: Then you did most likely not execute this _after_ the value was changed, but only once on script initialization ... because this is how it works.

Comment: @CBroe can u plz elaborate a bit. I didn't get what u meant

Comment: The line of code you have shown gets the current input field value, but only once, at the point in time where that line is executed. If you change the input field contents afterwards, of course the `name` variable will not reflect this. In such a case, you need to read the value (again) _after_ it has been changed. Don't know if that solves your problem, but for anything else you have given way too little context. Please go read [ask] first, if you need further help on this.

Comment: Hi thanks the issue is solved finally